# Запретить пользователю Linux CentOS вводить команды в терминале

Tags: linux, bash, centos, putty, ssh-tunnel

Я использую Putty для создания ssh-туннеля между клиентской машиной Windows и сервером CentOS(для проброса портов). Мне нужно, чтобы окно Putty оставалось открытым, но пользователь не мог ничего вводить в терминале.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/48129/416190

Answer (score 2):

рекомендую использовать plink из того же пакета.
у него есть опция -N

```
-N        don't start a shell/command (SSH-2 only)
```

как раз то, что тебе нужно.

в Putty тоже есть такая галочка в разделе SSH - Don't start a shell or command at all
можно её поставить.

[image: Don't start a shell or command at all]

Comment: [PLINK is a free, open-source whole genome association analysis toolset,
designed to perform a range of basic, large-scale analyses in a computationally
efficient manner.](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/repoforge-x86_64/plink-1.07-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm.html)